# PHPmyAdmin with MySQL on the other host

Tags: 12.04, php, cloud, openstack

How can I install `PHPmyAdmin` with `MySQL` on the other node?

I actually have `OpenStack` cloud deployed and want to have installed `Apache` and `PHP` on one node and `MySQL` on the other node.

Now I want to install PHPMyAdmin inside first node.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set up PHPMyAdmin, you can edit the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file and set the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` value (and friends) to the IP address or DNS name of the MySQL server you are trying to connect to.

[PHPMyAdmin's documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#server-connection-settings) is quite good.  There's usually a block similar to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'your_server'; // MySQL hostname
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306'; // MySQL port 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']= 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'username'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password'; // MySQL password
```

You'll just need to point the 'host' value to the IP of your MySQL node and make sure TCP port 3306 is open inbound in your firewall at least for your Apache/PHP node.